# Use only the month in a date for a query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I'm looking for a way to manipulate the month in a request, which I get from a date. (It's not MVVM)

How i get the date :

```
<Calendar x:Name="selectionMois" DisplayMode="Year" SelectionMode="SingleDate" 
    DisplayModeChanged="selectionMois_DisplayModeChanged"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,55,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    AllowDrop="True" Height="185" Width="226">
```

And

```
private void selectionMois_DisplayModeChanged( object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e )
{
    selectionMois.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
    this.dtMois = selectionMois.DisplayDate;
    LabelMois_Refresh();

    if( listAgentsCoches != null )
    {
        if( listAgentsCoches.Count > 0 ) BtImprimer.IsEnabled = true;
        else BtImprimer.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else BtImprimer.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

`this.dtMonth` contains the date in `"YYYYY\MM\01"` format.

Now I have a query or want to select agents who have a contract (contrat) in the chosen month.

I would like to do something like:

```
StSQL ="SELECT DISTINCT Agent_Etablissement.Matricule, Nom, Prénom FROM Agent_Etablissement, Agents, contrats
        INNER JOIN CONTRATS ON Contrats.Matricule = Agents.Matricule AND  Contrats.IDEtablissement=Agent_Etablissement.IDEtablissement
        WHERE a contract exists for the chosen month
```

"Contrats" Table contain starting date & ending date (this one can be null).

How can I select only those contracts that exist in the selected month?

Edit : SQL server database

[image: database]

Comment: Since date time queries could be database specific, it would be interesting which database you are using.

Comment: SQL server, sorry !

Comment: Do you want to get any contracts matching a start or end date with the selected month, or do you want to get any contracts that span the selected month?  In your example what would be returned for the first row? It spans years so would you want every month to match?  Or only December or June?  Also, are you considering year in this?

Comment: for example if I choose October, all contracts that exist in October: no matter if they end in December, or if they end on October 15. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that date fin will always contain the last day of month e.g. 2019-02-28 and 2020-02-29?

Comment: No, "end date" can be in the middle of the month, or even on the 2nd. If an agent finishes his contract on 2019-10-02 for example, I still have to pick him up. It exists in October, only one day, but it exists, so i need it

Comment: @Sephystos one day or two days? Does end date of `2019-10-02` mean the contract expires just before 2nd or including 2nd of Oct? Does `2019-10-01` mean it should not be included since it expires on Nov-30 23:59?

Comment: To be more precise, if ending date is October 01, I must select it from the query yes, it should be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MONTH()` to select the month value from a Datetime.  The below should work, selecting any Contract where the selected date (month) is greater than the Start and less than End date (if it's not null).

```
SELECT DISTINCT Agent_Etablissement.Matricule, Nom, Prénom 
FROM Agent_Etablissement, Agents, contrats
INNER JOIN CONTRATS ON Contrats.Matricule = Agents.Matricule AND  Contrats.IDEtablissement=Agent_Etablissement.IDEtablissement
WHERE (MONTH(@myDate) BETWEEN MONTH(StartDate) AND MONTH(EndDate)) 
   OR (MONTH(StartDate) >= MONTH(@myDate) AND EndDate IS NULL )
```

Note: This doesn't consider the year, so would return all contracts that spanned October (if October was selected).

---

The below also considers the year:

```
WHERE (MONTH(@myDate) BETWEEN MONTH(StartDate) AND MONTH(EndDate) 
   OR (MONTH(StartDate) >= MONTH(@myDate) AND EndDate IS NULL)) 

  AND (YEAR(@myDate) BETWEEN YEAR(StartDate) AND YEAR(EndDate) 
   OR (YEAR(StartDate) >= YEAR(@myDate) AND EndDate IS NULL))
```

**Please note**: this answer is not robust when using a longer date range (for example, if `[DateDebut]` and `[DateFin]` span the beginning/end of a year this query will fail).  You could add more conditions to the query to handle cases when `month(DateDebut)` is greater than `month(DateFin)` (ie the dates span the beginning/end of a year).

However, a better approach is to filter `DateDebut` and `DateFin` using `>=`, `<=` operators or `BETWEEN` to filter the dates as shown in other answers.

For example:

```
WHERE [DateDebut] >= @monthStart
 AND ([DateFin] <= @monthEnd OR [DateFin] IS NULL)
```

Comment: Does it work if start and end date span across two years?

Answer (score 1):

> for example if I choose October, all contracts that exist in October: no matter if they end in December, or if they end on October 15.

translates to

```
SELECT * FROM CONTRACTS
WHERE 
      ([DateDebut] >= '20191001' AND [DateDebut] <= EOMONTH('20191001')) -- starting in Oct
   OR ([DateFin] >= '20191001'   AND [DateFin] <= EOMONTH('20191001')) -- ending in Oct
   OR ([DateDebut] < '20191001'  AND ([DateFin] > EOMONTH('20191001') OR [DateFin] IS null)) -- started before Oct, but not ended
```

---

## Example

```
create table contracts ( [Id] varchar(3), [DateDebut] Date , [DateFin] Date, [Name] varchar(50) );
insert into contracts (id, [DateDebut], [DateFin], [Name]) values 
('1', '20120618', '20190920','[-] Before Oct'),
('2', '20190915', '20191015','[+] Ends middle of Oct'), 
('3', '20191020', '20191021','[+] Fully in Oct'),
('4', '20191028', '20191224','[+] Ends after Oct'),
('5', '20191128', '20191224','[-] After Oct'),
('6', '20190901', '20191001','[+] Ends 1st of Oct'),
('7', '20191001', '20191201','[+] Starts 1st of Oct'),
('8', '20191001', '20191031','[+] Full month'),
('9', '20191031', '20191201','[+] Starts 31st of Oct'),
('10', '20190901', '20191201','[+] Starts before Oct and ends after Oct');


SELECT * FROM CONTRACTS
WHERE 
--NOT(
      ([DateDebut] >= '20191001' AND [DateDebut] <= EOMONTH('20191001')) -- starting in Oct
   OR ([DateFin] >= '20191001'   AND [DateFin] <= EOMONTH('20191001')) -- ending in Oct
   OR ([DateDebut] < '20191001'  AND ([DateFin] > EOMONTH('20191001') OR [DateFin] IS null)) -- started before Oct, but not ended
--)
```

returns

```
Id  DateDebut   DateFin     Name
2   2019-09-15  2019-10-15  [+] Ends middle of Oct
3   2019-10-20  2019-10-21  [+] Fully in Oct
4   2019-10-28  2019-12-24  [+] Ends after Oct
6   2019-09-01  2019-10-01  [+] Ends 1st of Oct
7   2019-10-01  2019-12-01  [+] Starts 1st of Oct
8   2019-10-01  2019-10-31  [+] Full month
9   2019-10-31  2019-12-01  [+] Starts 31st of Oct
10  2019-09-01  2019-12-01  [+] Strats before Oct and ends after Oct
```

Just to be sure WERE NOT (...) returns

```
Id  DateDebut   DateFin     Name
1   2012-06-18  2019-09-20  [-] Before Oct
5   2019-11-28  2019-12-24  [-] After Oct
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b91be/1/0)

Note: I use '20191001' and not '2019-10-01' to avoid a scenario where it means the 10th of January, instead of 1st of October.